# Discord py - creating a channel in a certain category in a "on_raw_reaction_add" function?

Tags: discord, discord.py

**Hey guys, I have a problem I can't solve!**

How can I create a channel in a certain category?

My Code looks like:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
    user = payload.user_id
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    
    if user == 762903825866424320:
        return
    
    if emoji == "":
        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
        }
        ticket_nr = random.randint(100,999)
        await guild.create_text_channel(f'ticket-{ticket_nr}', overwrites=overwrites)

        member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
        role = await guild.create_role(name=f"ticket-{ticket_nr}")
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

**And a second question:**

I want to give the user who clicks on the emoji a role named ticket-{random-number} and only he and the role **Support** can access the channel! How do I have to change the overwrites?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question:

```py
category = guild.get_channel(CATEGORY_ID)
await category.create_text_channel(...)
```

For your second question:
I wouldn't recommend you to create a role with a random number, that's a pain to manage. Instead, when creating the ticket channel, you can overwrite it so only the Support role and the member can see it.

```py
support_role = ctx.guild.get_role(SUPPORT_ROLE_ID)
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
    support_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: I edited the code now and it works for the category - thanks :D
But now I have the problem that ctx is not defined - for the support_role I can use guild.get_role(ID) without the ctx but how do I get the author without the ctx?

Comment: Okay it works now - I replace "ctx.athor" with "member" and defined member with "discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)" - But thank you for your help :)